# Ожидание json от API и последующие действия. Python

Tags: python, json, iot

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при получении json объекта выполнять определённые действия (скрипты).
Допустим, на сервер пришёл json следующего содержания:

```
{
"action": "set-light"
"parameters":{
  "state": "on"
   }
}
```

Из него нужны значения set-light и on, исходя из этих значений, уже if'ами выполнять скрипты.
Надеюсь выразился понятно, это мой первый вопрос на stackoverflow.

Comment: Здесь суть не в значениях, а в ключах которые вам нужно читать, нужно ориентироваться именно на них. Если json приходит строкой - используем json_dict = json.loads(json_string), если в формате dict - тогда это нужно упустить и перейти к следующему, например:
if json_dict.get('action') == 'set-light':
или
if json_dict.get('parameters', {}).get('state') == 'on':

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if dict['action'] == 'set-light':
if dict['parametrs']['state'] == 'on'
```